# how to add multiple elements in row bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootsrtap-4 I am designing one page in HTML using bootstrap-4, But facing some issue while to make it responsive it should work in e.g, Laptop-L,Laptop-M and i-padd, while design it, its working in only for Laptop-L not M size and i-padd, can someone see me code and tell me what should i do to design this page.

Here is my code:

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-10">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4">    
                <div className="fontStyle">
                    <span className="">1</span>
                    <!-- <div className="displayBlk"> -->
                    <label type="text">Select Technology</label>

                        <select value=""  className="selectpicker btn btn-labeled btn-start">
                            <option value="">None Selected</option>
                            <option value="">Hello </option>
                            <option value="">World </option>
                        </select>
                    <!-- </div> -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4 rowOne">
                <div className="fontStyle">
                    Select Question Type                    
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Code Type</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Non Code Type</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <div className="fontStyle">
                    Number Of Questions
                    <select value="" onChange="" className="selectpicker btn btn-labeled btn-start">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="">01</option>
                        <option value="">02</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of 10 col row -->
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-2">
        <span className="">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Reset</button>
        </span>
        <span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">+</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end of main row -->
```

First Screen where its showing in L-Size Screen:

[first screen output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rycDH.png)

Second screen where its showing in M-size screen:

[second screen output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9k67.png)

What I am looking for actual output:

[actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoDkX.png)

can someone please guide me how can i achieve this design.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider making it a table. Since it is looking like that from your pictures. Also, I would suggest not to put multiple elements into a Grid Formation.

Let me give you an example. In your sample code you have:

```
<div className="col-md-2">
    <span className="">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bt-sm">Reset</button>
    </span>
    <span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">+</button>
    </span>
 </div>
```

I would suggest making it like so:

```
<div class="col-md">
    <span className="">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bt-sm">Reset</button>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="col-md">
    <span className="">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">+</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Make the elements as responsive as possible in their own mini world, if you like. Thing, as you show, get especially bad when you have buttons and text which are probably on a different z-axis.

The same principle applies for all your code.

Comment: How can we make it in table?,Actually in that picture there is plus button when user click on that its going to create the same row,coz of that i am trying to use grid system and put multiple elements in that.